# Date format parse 2019-08-07T20:11:59.6250889+09:30 to UTC Java LocalDateTime

Tags: java, date

I tried to convert  date string 2019-08-07T20:11:59.6250889+09:30 
to LocalDateTime format yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss format

```
String date = "2019-08-07T20:11:59.6250889+09:30";
DateTimeFormatter format = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSXXX");
LocalDateTime startDate = LocalDateTime.parse(date, format);
```

Stack Trace

```
Exception in thread "main" java.time.format.DateTimeParseException: Text '2019-08-07T20:11:59.6250889+09:30' could not be parsed at index 23
    at java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter.parseResolved0(DateTimeFormatter.java:1949)
    at java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter.parse(DateTimeFormatter.java:1851)
    at java.time.LocalDateTime.parse(LocalDateTime.java:492)
    at Testing.main(Testing.java:11)
```

Comment: and ....?  What happened ?

Comment: Exception in thread "main" java.time.format.DateTimeParseException: Text '2019-08-07T20:11:59.6250889+09:30' could not be parsed at index 0
 at java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter.parseResolved0(DateTimeFormatter.java:1949)
 at java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter.parse(DateTimeFormatter.java:1851)
 at java.time.LocalDateTime.parse(LocalDateTime.java:492)
 at Testing.main(Testing.java:11)

Comment: maybe you want `2019` ?

Comment: sorry I added wrong code updated it still getting error

Comment: There aren't enough fractions. There are 7 in your input but only 3 `S`'s in the pattern.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your format is built-in.

```
    String date = "2019-08-07T20:11:59.6250889+09:30";
    DateTimeFormatter format = DateTimeFormatter.ISO_OFFSET_DATE_TIME;
    LocalDateTime startDate = LocalDateTime.parse(date, format);
    System.out.println(startDate);
```

Output:

> 2019-08-07T20:11:59.625088900

The format is ISO 8601. Formatters for the most important variants of ISO 8601 are built into java.time. So don’t struggle with writing your own format pattern string. Just use the predefined `DateTimeFormatter.ISO_OFFSET_DATE_TIME`.

@shmosel is correct in the comment: `DateTimeFormatter` takes the number of decimals literally, so to parse a fraction of 7 decimals you would have needed `SSSSSSS` (7 `S`). java.time also has got the capability of parsing a variable number of decimals. For that you would need a `DateTimeFormatterBuilder` and its `appendFraction` method.

By your question title did you mean that you wanted the time in UTC? That would require an explicit conversion (since your string is at offset +09:30 from UTC):

```
    LocalDateTime startDate = OffsetDateTime.parse(date)
            .withOffsetSameInstant(ZoneOffset.UTC)
            .toLocalDateTime();
```

> 2019-08-07T10:41:59.625088900

**Links**

- [Wikipedia article: ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601)
- [Documentation of `DateTimeFormatter.ISO_OFFSET_DATE_TIME`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.html#ISO_OFFSET_DATE_TIME)